# How to fix "Can't find variable: jasmine" error when trying to use jasmine-jquery?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'm trying to setup jasmine-jquery for use with Jasmine 2.4. My Gruntfile config looks like this:

```
jasmine : {
  main: {
    // src: 'htdocs/test/newjs/**/*.js',
    options: {
      specs: 'htdocs/test/newjs/*.js',
      vendor: 'htdocs/jslib/jasmine-jquery-1.5.0/jasmine-jquery.js',
      template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs'),
      templateOptions: {
        requireConfigFile: 'htdocs/js/config.js',
        requireConfig: {
          baseUrl: './htdocs/js/',
          callback: function($) {
            // Extra initialization here
          },
          paths: {
            jquery:   '../jslib/jquery-1.9.1/jquery.min',
            facebook: '../jslib/connect.facebook.net-test/en_US/all',
            'jquery.mobile':   '../jslib/jquery.mobile.touchonly-1.3.2/'+
                'jquery.mobile.custom.min',
             templates:  '../templates',
             config: 'empty' // Override config require since this plugin
                              // already pulls it into the test runner
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

I keep getting the error "Can't find variable: jasmine," however. Does anyone have any experience with this error? I've heard that jasmine-jquery may not play well with the newer versions of Jasmine. Thoughts?

Here's a screenshot of the error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The above snippet is invalid, it should be as following

```
var jasmine = {
  main: {
    // src: 'htdocs/test/newjs/**/*.js',
    options: {
      specs: 'htdocs/test/newjs/*.js',
      vendor: 'htdocs/jslib/jasmine-jquery-1.5.0/jasmine-jquery.js',
      template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs'),
      templateOptions: {
        requireConfigFile: 'htdocs/js/config.js',
        requireConfig: {
          baseUrl: './htdocs/js/',
          callback: function($) {
            // Extra initialization here
          },
          paths: {
            jquery:   '../jslib/jquery-1.9.1/jquery.min',
            facebook: '../jslib/connect.facebook.net-test/en_US/all',
            'jquery.mobile':   '../jslib/jquery.mobile.touchonly-1.3.2/'+
                'jquery.mobile.custom.min',
             templates:  '../templates',
             config: 'empty' // Override config require since this plugin
                              // already pulls it into the test runner
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unless the jasmine object is part of another object

Comment: it is part of another object; that's not the problem I don't think.